# Build Where Clause (not sure PredicateBuilder will work for me)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to query a database using LINQ.  I am joining TableA with TableB with TableC.

I have zero to many 'keywords' (don't know how many at design time) that I would like to look for within (LIKE '%%') several fields that are spread across the three tables.

Assuming three (3) keywords are entered into my search box:

In T-SQL I would have this -

```
SELECT tbl0.FieldA, tbl0.FieldB, tbl1.FieldC, tbl1.FieldD, tbl2.FieldE, tbl2.FieldF

FROM tbl0

JOIN tbl1 ON tbl0.KeyField = tbl1.KeyField

JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.KeyField = tbl2.KeyField

WHERE (tbl0.FieldA LIKE '%{keyword1}%' OR tbl1.FieldC LIKE '%{keyword1}%' OR tbl2.FieldE LIKE '%{keyword1}%' OR tbl0.FieldA LIKE '%{keyword2}%' OR tbl1.FieldC LIKE '%{keyword2}%' OR tbl2.FieldE LIKE '%{keyword2}%' OR tbl0.FieldA LIKE '%{keyword3}%' OR tbl1.FieldC LIKE '%{keyword3}%' OR tbl2.FieldE LIKE '%{keyword3}%')
```

Question is -- How do I 'dynamically' build this WHERE clause in LINQ?

NOTE #1 -- I do not (for reasons outside the scope of this question) want to create a VIEW across the three tables

NOTE #2 -- Because I am joining in this way (and I am still new to LINQ) I don't see how I can use the PredicateBuilder because I am not sure what TYPE (T) to pass into it?

NOTE #3 -- If it matters ... I am ultimately planning to return a strongly typed list of (custom) objects to be displayed in a GridView.

**EDIT - 8/17/2012 - 5:15 PM EDT**

The comment below is correct.

"The code the OP is looking for is **where any one of the fields contains any one of the keywords**."

Thanks everyone!

Comment: david.s - I don't think anyone has truly answered this question yet.  I just refreshed the page.  What am I missing?  The 'answer' below will not work.  The comment from Servy is correct ... the generated SQL will contain 'AND' instead of 'OR'.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution not using the PredicateBuilder. Just get all the items containing the first keyword and merge it with all the items containing the second keyword and so on. Not knowing anything about the context of the problem I can't tell if this will be efficient or not.

```
var query = from t0 in db.Table0
            join t1 in db.Table1 on t0.KeyField equals t1.KeyField
            join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.KeyField equals t2.KeyField
            select new
            {
                t0.FieldA, t0.FieldB,
                t1.FieldC, t1.FieldD,
                t2.FieldE, t2.FieldF
            };

string keyword = keywordsList[0];
var result = query.Where(x => x.FieldA.Contains(keyword) ||
                              x.FieldC.Contains(keyword) ||
                              x.FieldE.Contains(keyword));

for (int i = 1; i < keywordsList.Length; i++)
{
    string tempkey = keywordsList[i];
    result = result.Union(query.Where(x => x.FieldA.Contains(tempkey) ||
                                           x.FieldC.Contains(tempkey) ||
                                           x.FieldE.Contains(tempkey)));
}

result = result.Distinct();
```

Comment: That would result in getting all rows where each keyword exists in any one of the fields.  The code the OP is looking for is where any one of the fields contains any one of the keywords.  In other words, you need to OR each of your sub-expressions, but currently you are ANDing them.

Comment: Servy - I am fairly sure you are exactly right because I tried this last night.  When I set a breakpoint and looked at the SQL that was generated it was using the AND between each keyword (in the foreach loop).

Comment: This is correct => "The code the OP is looking for is **where any one of the fields contains any one of the keywords**."

Comment: @david.s - "Not knowing anything about the context of the problem I can't tell if this will be efficient or not."  So the 'challenge' is this.  One of the tables (tbl0) contains two VarChar(MAX) fields.  Initially there was a View created in SQL server that joined the three tables (tbl0, tbl1, tbl2) and **included these VarChar(MAX) fields**.  I found that even though I was not 'using' these fields (in the sense that I was not retrieving the data stored in them and displaying it on my Search Results page) ... simply having them in the View was killing the performance.

Comment: @david.s - Before you ask, "Why not just remove them from the View?" The answer is: Because they are being used in the WHERE and as far as I can tell if (a) they are going to be in the WHERE and (b) you are going to use a View, then they need be included in the View Definition.  As I stated above, even though I don't retrieve the data to display on the page, having two VarChar(MAX) fields in the View seems to be killing performance.

Comment: @david.s - When we had the view the PredicateBuilder worked just fine.  I was able to use it by setting the <T> to the class in the .dbml (created by the designer) which was named the same as the view.  I am using the code above to try to improve performance.  I need to use the VarChar(MAX) in the WHERE but I don't want to retrieve it.

Comment: @david.s - Sorry for the lengthy response!

Comment: @Glen The best way to test the effieciency is to time both methods and see which one is faster. If my answer is good you now have an alternative to using the PredicateBuilder, but only you can see if it is better or worse in terms of performance.

Comment: @Glen You should have included the last comments as edits in your question because the information you provided can probably help others give you better answers.

Comment: @david.s - It's not working.  From what I can see, the field value must EQUAL the keyword.  For example, if you search for 'green' then the field value must be 'green'.  If the field value is 'the green grass' then it doesn't return results.  Looking at the SQL that is generate, the LIKE keyword is there ... but the percent symbols are not.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @david.s - One other (minor) thing.  I think 'from' should be 'in' here - join t1 **from** db.Table1 on t0.KeyField equals t1.KeyField - and here - join t2 **from** db.Table2 on t1.KeyField equals t2.KeyField